# yesod devel does not work anymore after upgrading to GHC 7.10.2

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, yesod

I've upgraded to `ghc 7.10.2` this morning. After doing that `yesod devel` does not seem to recompile the project properly since I cannot see any changes I'm making to the code, even though it seems to recompile some sources. I can only see the changes I've made after doing a `cabal install` (cabal-version is 1.22.6.0) which takes quite a lot of time.

How can I restore `yesod devel` to it's former functionality with `ghc 7.10.2`?

Comment: have you tried to recompile the yesod-bins? Most likely quite a few packages are broken and I would recommend recompiling them all after an update

Comment: Yep, recompiled them right away. I'm using `cabal build` and `cabal run` now to work around the issue.

Comment: You could try [stack](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/06/announcing-first-public-beta-stack). Might take care of stuff automatically.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: I'm running Archlinux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the latest version of `yesod-bin` (currently: `1.4.14`) fixed the issue for me.